# Problema ao criar ReportViewer em asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Instalei a package "Install-Package MvcReportViewer" via Package Manager Console e ao tentar criar o ReportViewer dá um erro de não encontrada a referência.

Meu código:

View

```
@using MvcReportViewer; <-- Aqui dá erro

<h2>Invoice</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RelatorioInvoice", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div>
        <label>
           <span>Invoice/Credit note: </span> 
            @Html.TextBox("Range1", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style = "width:100px;" }) 

            <span> até </span>
             @Html.TextBox("Range2", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style = "width:100px;" })

            <span>Série: </span> 
            @Html.TextBox("txtSerie", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style = "width:50px", maxlength = "2" })

            <span>Tipo: </span> 
            @Html.TextBox("Tipo", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style = "width:50px;", maxlength = "2" }) 

            <span>CIA: </span>             
            @Html.DropDownList("ItemsListCIA", null, "Sel...", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style = "width:90px;" })

            <input class="btn btn-padrao-bv" type="submit" id="btnPesquisar" value="Pesquisar"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("Comentário", "Comentario", null , new { target = "_blank", @class="modal-link" })

        </label>
        <p>
            <label>
                @ViewBag.Message
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>

}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
        $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
        $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<div style="margin-top: 20px;">

    @Html.MvcReportViewer(
    "/TestReports/TestReport",
    new { Parameter1 = "Hello World!", Parameter2 = DateTime.Now, Parameter3 = 12345, Parameter4 = DateTime.UtcNow },
    new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" })

    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade comentario-modal" 
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra o arquivo `~/Views/Web.config` (não é o do diretório raiz, é outro) e adicione a seguinte entrada:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcReportViewer" /> <!-- Esta aqui -->
        <add namespace="MeuProjeto" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Se o Visual Studio ficar marcando erro de sintaxe, feche todas as *Views* e faça um *Rebuild* na solução.

Comment: funcionou, porem quando tento criar o "@Html.MvcReportViewer" igual no exemplo que me mandou, ainda não funciona. Dei o Rebuild e não funcionou.

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona? Dá erro de sintaxe? O código falha na execução? Seja mais específico.

Comment: Da erro na Referencia do "MvcReportViewer" da View, portanto não deixa criar o controle "@Html.MvcReportViewer" igual do exemplo.

Comment: Pode abrir outra pergunta detalhando o erro, com a mensagem específica?

Comment: Refiz tudo aqui e funcionou. Valeu